# Urine - can I pray or not

Tags: salat

**

- Urine:

**

If urine drops after you urinate onto your underwear, does that mean I can't pray unless I change it?

Or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must change it as it comes under najis. However there is leeway for people who suffer from incontinence and it’s said that in hanafi fiqh 5cm radius is allowed for those who struggle with controlling urine